# How to overwrite a single partition in Snowflake when using Spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way for Spark to read a single date partition from a Snowflake table, update it and then to overwrite this single date partition. Concurrent writes should be supported. Currently Spark has two overwrite modes, so I don't see a way to overwrite a single partition. It's an easy thing to do in Iceberg, as there overwrite mode overwrites only a single partition. Am I missing out some obvious solution?

I am interested in a solution that would not require transactions or complex SQLs. Ideally, the same behavior as in Iceberg, that is operation that allows to overwrite a single partition

Comment: Snowflake doesn’t have partitions - at least not in the sense that I think you mean - so your question doesn’t make much sense. It’s a columnar database with micro-partitions that are insert-only. If you want to update records in a Snowflake table then you just update them

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that Snowflake has clustering. This may improve the performance when the scope of updates is within a single partition. I see that it's hard to say to Snowflake that it should only overwrite micropartitions for some clustering key. I see Snowflake does not have any easy way to achieve overwrite_partition behaviour, which is in my opinion inconvenient.

Comment: Hi - you appear not to understand how Snowflake is architected and are applying techniques that you’ve found useful with another DBMS to Snowflake - when they are not relevant or applicable. Snowflake micro-partitions are read-only so you can’t overwrite them; you can’t overwrite anything in Snowflake. When you “update” something in Snowflake you are effectively inserting data into new micro-partitions  and Snowflake is flagging the old version as not current. If you have a specific performance issue in Snowflake maybe update your question with that and people may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean I want Spark to create a bunch of files with data for a 'day' and for Snowflake to overwrite it's old files for this day with Spark generated files. Micropartions are just files/bunch of files + metadata if I get it correctly. Nothing stops it from creating new partitions based on Spark output. Overall goal is achievable, but not so easy than, at least, in Iceberg, where you need not to write 'not Spark' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake doesn’t hold data as files (assuming that you are using standard tables) so in this case your last comment, particularly “Snowflake to overwrite it's old files”, still doesn’t make much sense.

Assuming your Snowflake tables have a column that indicates a “day” then you can delete these records and load your latest Spark files into Snowflake. If your new set of files is a change to data in the existing records in Snowflake then you can potentially insert/update/delete with a merge statement.

If you are talking about some type of Snowflake External table (that sits over files held in a cloud storage system) then you can manage those files outside of Snowflake and just refresh the metadata in Snowflake as necessary.

If you’re just trying to move data from Spark to Snowflake then I’d start by reading [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#moving-data-from-spark-to-snowflake) part of the documentation